# how to change Session ID for each request in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have Created ASP.Net,C# web application. I would like to get the new Session id for each time requesting a web page.And assign the Session id value to a label.Hence, i tried following,

```
            string sessionId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
            LblSessionvar.Text = Convert.ToString(sessionId);
```

now, the problem is it shows same Session Id each time when i run the Web Application,it does not change the Session ID.
( i have tried with  cookieless session it works nice and it changes Session ID as i expected but,i would like to achieve this with Cookies).

Comment: This is the default behavior of .Net for maintaining session. All session information stored on server is identified based on the session id passed by the client. What functionality you want to achieve by changing session id? I don't think there is any good reason to change the session id. Please elaborate your functionality.

Comment: i want to get the unique session id for each time when i open the web page.But, it shows same session id each time.

Comment: i want to get the unique session id for each time when i open the web page.But, it shows same session id each time.

Comment: @Ram session id is used to uniquely identify the client, i dont know what you are doing with session id, if you want new id each time then first get session id ..do your work .. clear session then get again this is the way I think of

Answer (score 0):

Call;

```
Session.Abandone();
```

and

```
Response.Cookies("ASP.NET_SessionId").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-30)
```

This will may help you; By the way, why do you need sessionId?

Comment: i want to store the Session id value in SQL table with some other data from textboxes when clicking Save button in ASP.net web page

Comment: Session Id is storen on Cookies. This refer to SessionId on Server Side. For this reason, you have to call Session.Abondone() and cookie expires date change request.

Comment: Where should i call Session.Abondone(); and Expires. Now i have placed my above codes in (!IsPostback)

Comment: https://www.tigraine.at/2008/07/17/session-handling-in-aspnet

Look at this link. It will may help you.

Comment: Also you can call ; Session.Abondone(); and Expires when your current request relation finish with sessions. For example at the and of the PageLoad() method or etc.

Comment: If you share a piece of code with me, I can show a bit more. Share with me one class that you want to implement this structure

Comment: Ok CanBey i will try as you suggested and post my result here